# Xamarin IOS build fails when adding Firebase project (UnpackFrameworks Task Failed)

Tags: firebase, compiler-errors, xamarin.ios

Working on my project and when I add Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging (or other firebase projects), I get the following error below when trying to build IOS only.
I tried deleting files in obj/bin, cleaning solution, rebuilding, restarting computer, going to regedit to enable longpaths, but nothing works. It seems like during the build, HotRestart unzips the framework file, then may try again and it wont overwrite and fails. When I uninstall the Firebase projects everything works perfectly. Been going crazy trying to figure this out!

Using Visual Studio 2022 trying to run on real device IphoneX.

2> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.HotRestart.targets(75,3): error MSB4018: The "UnpackFrameworks" task failed unexpectedly.
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.HotRestart.targets(75,3): error MSB4018: System.IO.IOException: The file 'obj\iPhone\Debug\Frameworks\FirebaseFirestore.framework\FirebaseFirestore' already exists.
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.HotRestart.targets(75,3): error MSB4018: at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.HotRestart.targets(75,3): error MSB4018: at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite, Boolean checkHost)
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.HotRestart.targets(75,3): error MSB4018: at System.IO.FileInfo.CopyTo(String destFileName)
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.HotRestart.targets(75,3): error MSB4018: at Xamarin.iOS.Tasks.Windows.Zip.CopyDirectory(String source, String destination) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/msbuild/Xamarin.iOS.Tasks.Windows/Zip.cs:line 32
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.HotRestart.targets(75,3): error MSB4018: at Xamarin.iOS.Tasks.Windows.Zip.Extract(String sourceFileName, String destinationPath) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/msbuild/Xamarin.iOS.Tasks.Windows/Zip.cs:line 18
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.HotRestart.targets(75,3): error MSB4018: at Xamarin.iOS.HotRestart.Tasks.UnpackFrameworks.Execute() in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/msbuild/Xamarin.iOS.Tasks.Windows/Tasks/UnpackHotRestartFrameworks.cs:line 55
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.HotRestart.targets(75,3): error MSB4018: at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.HotRestart.targets(75,3): error MSB4018: at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the below link.

https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin/issues/437

Another workaround is to edit Xamarin.iOS.HotRestart.targets file:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.HotRestart.targets
Path depends on your VS version.

Search UnpackFrameworks node and add ContinueOnError="true". Like this:

```
    <UnpackFrameworks ContinueOnError="true"
        ReferencedAssemblies="@(AssembliesWithFrameworks)"
        IntermediateOutputPath="$(DeviceSpecificIntermediateOutputPath)">

        <Output TaskParameter="Frameworks" ItemName="_UnpackedFramework" />
    </UnpackFrameworks>
```

Comment: This worked for me like a charm. Only need to restart VS2022 after this edit. And if you are using community edition or you are one a different drive, change the path accordingly .